# Can I manually type in large cell range?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So I want to be able to select a range to work with - for example A1 to ZZ200. Without having to highlight that whole area is there some way that I can just type in the range that I want to work with?? I'm looking for something like the CTRL G goto button.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact, you can do it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> as shown below. You can also click in the box in the second image, type in the range, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

See the imagse below from Excel 2013. It works exactly the same way in 2010.

[image: GoTo Box]

[image: Excel 2013]

Comment: And in Excel 2007.

Comment: Should be the same thing...

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue! Any chance you would have an answer to my other question - which is listed under:    
Strange behavior of left arrow key in Excel 2010

Comment: I did some checking and I'm unable to reproduce the behavior that you described.

I'm glad to have been a help with this one. If you could mark the answer as Accepted, I'd appreciate it.